# is it possible to determine local time of the machine from which an api request is made?

Tags: java, datetime, servlets, httprequest, localtime

I want to know the current time of the machine from which a request is made to my api written in java. Is it possible to do that using some function of HttpServletRequest?

Comment: Have a timestamp (including time zone) as part of the request?

Comment: your question could include some research done by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! Not using the java api request as requests are created by users .But  if you have a UI application sending requests to java application that application can get the client machine's date & your Ui code can send this date in request.

> var currentDate = new Date();

you can format and send the date now to server.